# How should I perform cross-validation for my ANN-SVM hybrid model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cross-validation

I am working on a small hybrid learning project involving ANN and SVM. However, I am currently facing a challenge during the training phase. I am utilizing a simple ANN with the last layer providing five features. These five features are then passed to the SVM. Now, I have a doubt regarding the approach for cross-validation. Should I send every instance to the ANN at once and then perform cross-validation in the SVM, or should I conduct cross-validation for the entire ANN + SVM?

I am using ANN for feature side and SVM for classification.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not training the neural network and only training SVM, both approaches will result in the same number. For computational efficiency, I would chose the former - to feed-forward all neural network features at once and perform cross-validation training the svm.